# I encounter an endlessly processing request once this code is added

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I have no clue why this piece of code prevents my API from working properly. It causes all requests to process endlessly and if I remove it - everything works fine

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE");
});
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no call to `next()` so the request gets hung up here.  It doesn't advance to other request handlers (that's what `next()` does) and it doesn't send a response so the request just dies there and will probably eventually timeout.  Add `next()` like this:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE");
  next();
});
```